# Можно ли объекту std::atomiс задать memory_order по умолчанию?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++17, атомарность, std-atomic

У меня в приложении есть модуль с настройками, где каждый параметр представлен `std::atomiс`. Сейчас я начал задавать каждому такому параметру memory_order и например вместо `station_id_` приходится писать `station_id_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`. Т.к. таких обращений в коде очень много, это очень сильно стало раздувать код. Есть ли в С++ какой-то механизм который позволит задавать memory_order при инициализации объекта std::atomiс?

Comment: механизм наследования?)

Comment: Не уверен, что это хорошая идея. Во первых это может запутать людей, которые этот код читают. Во вторых с трудом представляются сценарии, где для экземпляра атомика везде будет стоять одинаковое слабое. И если вы где-то забудете поменять дефолтное сейчас, программа будет чуть медленней работать, а если поставить дефолтные слабое требование и забыть его поменять, будет неприятный плавающий баг.

Comment: Ввести свой тип с переопределенными оператороми присваивания и приведения типа, инкапсулирующий atomic?

Comment: @Chorkov тут появляется вопрос про оверхэда. Во-первых, это однозначно больше по памяти (я в ней немного ограничен в этом проекте, хоть и не сильно). Во-вторых т.к. это оператор доступа к элементу то увеличение времени доступа даже на 1 такт будет катастрофой и нивелируют всю прибыль, которую я пытаюсь тут наивно получить от использования смены модели доступа к памяти (компиляторы не всегда инлайнят функции доступа). Я сейчас думаю над коментарием Дмитрий Зиненко. Ему удалось посеять зерно сомнения в мои мысли =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя. Потому что нет никакого порядка по умолчанию у атомарных объектов. Есть порядок по умолчанию для конкретных операций, который зашит в интерфейсе соответствующих функций. Разумеется, по умолчанию всегда используется порядок, который не вызовет удивления у пользователя при использовании этих операций.

Любой порядок, отличный от последовательной согласованности, никогда не должен являться порядком по умолчанию, т.к. порождает неинтуитивное поведение. Поэтому нет никакого смысла делать класс `std::atomic`, в котором поведение по умолчанию разрешалось бы менять. Более того, `load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` это не захламление кода и информационный шум, наоборот — это хороший индикатор того, что к коду возможно стоит приглядеться. А вот если всё это скрыть, то специалист, который [может] будет искать баг связанный с многопоточностью, просто не заметит, что никакой синхронизации не происходит.

Comment: Забавный факт. Когда вы написали свой ответ, я читал очень хорошую статью о том как работает std::atomic на http://scrutator.me. Смотрю на ваш ник, и понимаю, что видел его где-то 2 минуты назад, но не могу вспомнить где. А потом до меня доходит что я читаю вашу статью =)